# Regular Expression in Oracle Sql

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

My following SQL is not working but when I use same regular expression in Java, it's work fine

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE REGEXP_LIKE
(MESSAGE, '^(92|0)?(3[0-9]{9})\\*([0-9]{4})\\*(([0-9]{3})|1000)$')
```

Please help what I am doing wrong.

i am comparing following string

```
03211234090*0000*75
```

Comment: +1 for making it work in Java!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in your search pattern: `\\*`.  This should be `\*`, as you only need one `\` to escape the `*`.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MESSAGE, '^(92|0)?(3[0-9]{9})\*([0-9]{4})\*(([0-9]{3})|1000)$')
```

The other problem is in the `\*(([0-9]{3})|1000)$` part - the last part of your string. The string you have provided `03211234090*0000*75` does not end with three digits between 0-9 or "1000".

`$` means the string must end with the expression immediately preceding it.

As a solution try putting `\*(([0-9]{2, 3})|1000)$` if your business logic allows this. This will allow the either two or three digits or `1000` after the last asterisk to be accepted and the row will be retrieved.

Comment: sorry for typo infact i am camparing 03211234090*0000*750. In java we have to put two \\. Thx its working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

The real question should be: how come it's working in java?
Since the string `03211234090*0000*75` doesn't match your regular expression - the las part (after the second asterix needs to have 3 digits or 1000 and you have only 2)

Comment: +1 for "how come it's working in Java?" I didn't even think about that!